# Matplotlib does not display the hatch of a patch in a legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm not sure if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong. My goal is to display a hatch in the legend but it does not work. The code I use for that is

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
...
def plot_legend(ax):
    ep = mpatches.Patch(color=[1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1], hatch='/',
        label=r'$\pi_e\ free$')
    cp = mpatches.Patch(color=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1], label='$\pi_e = exp(-60)$')
    #ax.legend(handles=[ep, cp], bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), 
    #    loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)

    pyl.legend(handles=[ep, cp],
         loc=1)

    return
```

The results is the following:

[image: The weird color in the legend is to show that is working.]

The version of matplotlib I'm using is 1.5.1 in a mac computer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Presumably the `color` keyword in `mpatches.Patch` is being applied for both `edgecolor` and `facecolor`. Your hatch might be there, just not visible because of the same color.

Explicitly specifying the `facecolor` should solve your problem:

`ep = mpatches.Patch(edgecolor=[1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1], facecolor=[0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1],
                     hatch='/', label=r'$\pi_e\ free$')`

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you, it did the job. It is still an odd behaviour, I guess.

Comment: After digging around for many time this post finally solved my problem! Thanks!